# what is $\mathcal{F}_t^0$-optional positive process $\tilde a(q)$ defined in Hayashi et al?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

In the paper of[Hayashi et al.](http://www.numdam.org/item/10.1214/11-AIHP432.pdf) in assumption D is defined the following convergence in probability $A(q)_t^n \overset{\mathbb{P}}\to \int_{0}^{t} a(q)_s ds$. what does it means the process $a(q)$ is $\mathcal{F}_t^0$-optional positive process?